# A more elegant way to exit failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `Question` model that has many `Answer`.

I'm validating that not more than three answers are created for each question:

```
has_many :answers, -> { order(position: :asc) }, before_add: :set_nested

private    
def set_nested(answer)
  if answers.size > 3
    errors.add(:base, "Too many answers.")
    raise "Unable to create answer."
  else
    answer.question ||= self
  end
end
```

The code is working, when there are too many answers I get "rollback transaction" and "RuntimeError: Unable to create answer."

But then threre are 20 lines of path references to different lines in `collection_association.rb`. It's the typical look when you have done something wrong.

**Is this as it should be or am I doing the validation a bit too brutal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress the ugly `error stacktrace` and error raised due to `before_add` callback, what you can do is `rescue` the raised error.

For example:

Update your `question.rb` as below:

```
class AnswersLimitExceeded < StandardError; end ## Add this

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :answers, -> { order(position: :asc) }, before_add: :set_nested

private    
def set_nested(answer)
  if answers.size > 3
    errors.add(:base, "Too many answers.")
    raise AnswersLimitExceeded, "Unable to create answer." ## Change here
  else
    answer.question ||= self
  end
end
```

After this update the `create` action in your `QuestionsController`

```
def create
  ## ...
  begin
    if @question.save
      ## ...
    else
      ## ..
    end 
  rescue AnswersLimitExceeded
    render action: 'new' 
  end
end
```

This way whenever `AnswersLimitExceeded` is raised within your `Question` model while creating the `associated answers` then it is rescued at *controller level* thereby suppressing the specific error `AnswersLimitExceeded` with message `Too many answers` elegantly.

Also, if you notice I created a separate Error class i.e., `AnswersLimitExceeded` so that I rescue `ONLY` this particular exception in Controller and not all others.